# sync android todolist with google calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-json

I'm new in making of android apps. I've recently built an android Todo-list app. The user enters a title for the " ToDo" ( and if the user wants, he/ she can set a date and/or time to be reminded at the given date/ time). All that information is stored in the database of the app. My question is: Is there a way to sync the information  (the date, time and title) with Google calendar? Here is an example of my app: 
http://prntscr.com/3txzkt
Is it even possible to sync these information with Google calendar?, and if so, how do I do it.  Where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head over to [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events).

**Using the proper API you can achieve what you are looking for.**
[Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/)
OR more Specificity
[Google Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) would do.

Google Tasks is embedded into Google Calender so its almost the same thing.
Go through the document before you start.

All the Best!

Comment: Happy to have helped!